# How to tell if SSL socket incomming request is a POST request?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I am using the SSLServerSocketFactory in which HTTPS data will come through incoming requests. Is there any way that I can tell that the request was a POST request? I do have a JSON mapping that will indicate whether or not the request was a POST. However, I was wondering if there was a way to tell from the Object itself.

Comment: JSON is part of the HTTPS message *body*. The type of message, i.e. POST/GET/... is located in the HTTPS message *header*, in a field called Request Method.

Comment: Maybe you would like to use some simple http server (with ssl) rather than parse the data from the socket manually.
Using class HttpServer resp. HttpsServer is easy: see example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

Comment: You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP. Not just the rather trivial fact that POST would be the first four bytes of the first line of the request.

Comment: @SHG do you recommend any libraries to read the entire POST request? Currently I've been reading off the input stream using the jackson JsonFactory. However this only handles the body as you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're coding, but any *web framework* will give you exactly what you need. Not sure if it fits your requirements though.

Comment: I don't think I have the option to use web framework. I would use Spring if I could. I may end up experimenting with the HttpServer class as suggested above. It appears to have access to the request body and other things that I'd like.

Comment: "...I was wondering if there was a way to tell from the Object itself..." What object?